# How to prevent bootstrap dropdown from adding dropup class

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using a bootstrap-3 [Split button dropdown](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns-split) that sometimes adds a 'dropup' class when clicked. I think this is because of a container size calculation, but is it a clean way to 'force' it to always do 'dropdown'?

Comment: That must be part of your code. Bootstrap does no such container calculation for dropdowns, and AFAICT its `dropdown.js` doesn't mention the `dropup` class.

Comment: @cvrebert is right. Dropup must be manually added.

Comment: But there is a dropup variation here -> http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns-dropup

Comment: @JonBaron Yes, and it's *completely manual*. If you don't add `dropup` to the element yourself, it will always be a dropdown and its menu will always open downwards.

Comment: Post a JS Fiddle with your alleged counterexample.

Comment: To prevent dropup in BS4: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59680275/5519644