# Bootstrap 3 dropdown toggle is adding 'dropup' class on page scroll

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

**Wanted Outcome:**

Prevent boostrap from adding `dropup` class to the dropdown toggle element

---

Depending where you are on the page (as in the dropdown has more "space" below it than it does above), the dropdown's options either display below or above the actual select. I looked at the bootstrap documentation, and only came across this:

[Bootstrap Dropdown](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns)

> Wrap the dropdown's trigger and the dropdown menu within .dropdown, or another element that declares position: relative;. Then add the menu's HTML.

Then for up:

> Dropdown menus can be changed to expand upwards (instead of downwards) by adding .dropup to the parent.

The wrapper however, didn't have any of these 2 classes at all. Therefore, I added the `dropdown` class to the wrapper:

[image]

You can see that there is more space on the bottom of the page than the top still.

[image]

However, when scrolling up on the page (with the class `dropdown` added to the wrapper), bootstrap is automatically adding the `dropup` class:

[image]

I can override with CSS/jQ most likely, but I didn't know if there was anything I was missing as far as default boostrap classes or data attributes that need to be assigned to the wrapper and/or dropdown toggle element itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some research (for Bootstrap 3), all the `select` elements were using `selectpicker()`, and to force these `select` elements to always "drop down", the following is needed:

`$('yourSelector').selectpicker({ dropupAuto: false });`

Answer (score 3):

2020 update, for future searchers. To avoid or prevent your `dropdown` from auto adding the `dropup` or any other auto flipping classes, you can do this.

You can add a `data-flip` attribute to your `dropdown-toggle` element with a value of `false`.

This is for Bootstrap 4 though, have not tried on other versions.

Example:

```
<a href='#' class='dropdown-toggle' role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle='dropdown' aria-haspopup='true' aria-expanded='false' data-flip='false'>BUTTON</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Sorry I'm late to the party @Rob. Yes, selectpicker() is part of the [Bootstrap-Select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/)

If you are not familiar with this check it out. It has lots of functionality that is missing in Bootstrap.

Note: if you see the class 'selectpicker' you are dealing with Bootstrap-Select